# Question about Eigenvalues of Hermetian Operators Being Real Numbers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, complex-numbers

I'm still slogging through Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum and I've reached another area that baffles me.

Susskind uses the following to show that the eigenvalues of Hermitian operators are real numbers:

Given $L$ as a Hermetian operator, $\lambda$ as its eigenvalue and $|\lambda\rangle$ as its eigenvector

$$L|\lambda \rangle = \lambda |\lambda \rangle$$

$$\langle \lambda | L^\dagger = \langle \lambda | \lambda^*$$

since $L$ is Hermetian, $$L = L^\dagger$$ and

$$\langle \lambda | L = \langle  \lambda | \lambda^*$$

multiply  $$\langle \lambda |$$ to the first equation and $$|\lambda \rangle$$ to the second and you have

$$\langle \lambda |L|\lambda \rangle = \lambda \langle \lambda |\lambda \rangle$$

and

$$\langle \lambda | L |\lambda \rangle = \lambda^* \langle  \lambda |\lambda \rangle$$

which means

$$\lambda = \lambda^*$$ and the eigenvalues are real numbers

**Question**
Why does $\lambda = \lambda^*$mean that the eigenvalues are real numbers?

Comment: Think of conjugates, only real numbers are their own conjugate s

Comment: $$a+ \mathrm i b~= ~a-\mathrm i b\,,$$

Comment: What do you think of $b\;?$

Comment: I strongly advice you to learn some math (necessarily doing some exercises). Those are very basic facts and going further everything will only get harder for you.

Comment: Two books with worked solutions that could be worth reading and follow through the solutions: Squires: Problems in Q.M. and Schaum: Quantum Mechanics

Comment: @OON: I am, actually. Linear Algebra in parallel with Susskind's book.

Comment: @count_to_10: Crap. I am stupid. Thanks for the reminder (about real numbers and complex conjugates)

Comment: I self study completely, so been there, done that. At the top of each page of my notes, I write: what are my assumptions? That's where I always get stuck, thinking I know something I actually don't. Best of luck with it and stick with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us write the eigenvalues as follows:
$$\lambda=a+ib$$
Where $a$ and $b$ are real. By definition we must therefore have:
$$\lambda^*=a-ib$$
Equating these gives us:
$$a+ib=a-ib$$
$$2ib=0$$
$$b=0$$
and therefore:
$$\lambda=a$$
Which is a real number.

Comment: …and, of course, I forgot this as well…which I'm almost positive was covered previously in Susskind.